# Compiling Python via Pyenv on Archlinux but missing OpenSSL

Tags: python, archlinux, pyenv

I am trying to install python via pyenv on my new ArchLinux install

```
pyenv install 3.5.1Downloading Python-3.5.1.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.1/Python-3.5.1.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.5.1...
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?

Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem.
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems


BUILD FAILED (Arch Linux using python-build 20160602)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20170515113212.3725
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20170515113212.3725.log

Last 10 log lines:
(cd /home/maximilian/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/share/man/man1; ln -s python3.5.1 python3.1)
if test "xupgrade" != "xno"  ; then \
    case upgrade in \
        upgrade) ensurepip="--upgrade" ;; \
        install|*) ensurepip="" ;; \
    esac; \
     ./python -E -m ensurepip \
        $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
fi
Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 7.1.2 requires SSL/TLS
```

And it failes due to missing OpenSSL support. I had it running on my previous Arch installation but I can't remember what I did back then.

The FAQ in the Wiki does not provide a working solution

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please try it.:

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/openssl-1.0 \
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib64/openssl-1.0 \
pyenv install -v 3.5.1
```

ArchLinux packages:

```
$ pacman -Q | grep openssl
openssl 1.1.0.e-1
openssl-1.0 1.0.2.k-3
python-pyopenssl 17.0.0-1
python2-pyopenssl 17.0.0-1
```

Answer (score 4):

The [pyvenv FAQ mention an issue similar to what you are reporting](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems#error-the-python-ssl-extension-was-not-compiled-missing-the-openssl-lib). Their solution is to use

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/openssl \
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib64 \
pyenv install -v 3.5.1
```

Also it's not Python that needs SSL but only pip. Arch's own Python 3 package [compiles with `--without-ensurepip`](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/python#n71), so you could try

```
CONFIGURE_OPTS="--without-ensurepip" \
pyenv install -v 3.5.1
```

Comment: Yeah but what can I do to get the build process to work with pyenv.

Comment: I tried this, but to no avil. Most frustrating is the fact that I got It working on a different machine