# Pyenv on Amazon Linux fails to build due to openssl

Tags: amazon-ec2, openssl, pyenv

I’m having the exact same issue as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976068/compiling-python-via-pyenv-on-archlinux-but-missing-openssl) with respect to compiling Python 3.7+ on Amazon Linux 2 using Pyenv. I’ve tried building openssl1.1 from source and still get the same error of build fails due to openssl not being compiled. Following the recommended instruction of setting the right flag variable to the path of openssl and then running Pyenv install still didn’t work. Does anyone have a solution for this on Amazon Linux?

Answer (score 12):

This finally worked for me

```
sudo yum remove openssl-devel.x86_64
sudo yum autoremove
sudo yum install openssl11-devel
```

Comment: This is what I do for Amazon Linux 2 also. For the upcoming Amazon Linux 2022, there isn't an `openssl11-devel` package. Using the included one (`openssl-devel`) worked for me. Here is the yum/dnf list I use for install: `sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y && sudo yum install -y zlib-devel bzip2 bzip2-devel readline-devel sqlite sqlite-devel tk-devel libffi-devel xz-devel
`

Comment: This worked for me too. Was trying to install 3.10.11 on my Cloud9 instance, and was failing with "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'" errors. Running these commands fixed it for me. Thanks for the fix.